# Failure using getActiveSpreadsheet with webapp bound to Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

An odd thing is happening. Maybe someone can explain it or maybe there's a bug. I'm writing a webapp that runs from an Apps Script bound to a spreadsheet. The webapp runs normally when I open the spreadsheet using openById(), but not getActiveSpreadsheet(). When I load the page I get this message, "TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null. (line 11, file "Code")". It behaves like it's not bound to the spreadsheet.

However, if I run doGet() manually I do not get the error. Data is pulled successfully from the Log sheet. Here's my code... when I comment out line 1 and uncomment line 2 it works perfectly. Thanks in advance.

```
    function doGet() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Log');
      //  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abc123def456').getSheetByName('Log');
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
      t.data = data;
      var evaluatedTemplate = t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
      return evaluatedTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, probably a duplicate. I was inspired by that thread and came up with a different workaround that doesn't seem to require additional authorization by the end user.

Comment: Please share it in an answer, then.

Comment: Never mind. Failed work around

Answer (score 0):

Remove your 'doGet()' function. If your script is an add-on, it doesn't need a doGet(). Instead use onInstall, onOpen and then use HTML service to open pages.

You're sending google mixed signals.

Bound scripts and Webapps are different.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound